# Not able to delete Public IP address in azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I am trying to delete the public IP address from azure. I have already removed the associated Network Interface card from Azure but deleting the IP address is throwing the below error.

> Public IP address /subscriptions/ddddddd-ddddd-dddd-dddd-dddddddd/resourceGroups/atcsl/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/pip-VM1_Windows can not be deleted since it is still allocated to resource /subscriptions/ddddddd-ddddd-dddd-dddd-dddddddd/resourceGroups/atcsl/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/nic_VM1_Windows/ipConfigurations/ipconfig1. In order to delete the public IP, disassociate/detach the Public IP address from the resource. To learn how to do this, see aka.ms/deletepublicip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may just takes some minutes until deletion of the network interface went through. If you still see your Network Interface in your resource group

[image]

you can also just go to the IP configurations settings of the network interface and click on your configuration

[image]

then click "Disassociate" > "Save" and you can delete your public IP.

[image]